# Adding extra parameter to disable outputs

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters

So right now I'm doing a guessing program to test different methods of guessing in the game Mastermind.

It tests 3 different methods once right now. But for another piece of the homework, I have to run through each of those methods 100 more times to get the extra data. 
Except, I don't want to print out each of the steps that the method performs like what I did for the first three.

All I want are the results, for example however many tries the method took.

So, my teacher said it would help if I added an extra parameter to a function to disable output ( make them behave quietly).

How would adding a parameter disable the outputs in a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use that parameter in an if statement around all of your output lines.

```
void DoStuff(...., bool bEnableOutput )
{

...
   if ( bEnableOutput == true )
   {
      printf( "...." );
   }
}
```

That way you can just switch

```
DoStuff( ..., true );
```

to

```
DoStuff( ..., false );
```

depending on whether or not you want output.